# Docker Swarm and Nginx + Varnish

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, varnish, swarm

I have a docker-compose file that contains Nginx, PhpFpm and Varnish.

My Nginx works this way:
User connect to the website => Nginx (443) => Varnish (80) => Nginx (8080) => Phpfpm:9000 or others..

My project work well with "depends_on" config inside docker-compose.
But, with docker swarm, the depends_on is ignored.

There my problems starts..

My Varnish container, needs Nginx to be running, or its crash, due to the hostname defined on top of the configuration file :

```
# varnish config file
backend default {
  .host = "nginx";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 10s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 10s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 10s;
}
```

And, my nginx, needs varnish to be running or it's crash too...

```
# pass to varnish
location / {
    proxy_pass http://varnish;
}

upstream varnish {
    server varnish:80;
}
```

Soooo, varnish crashs because nginx is not up and nginx crashs because varnish is not up.

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Varnish container would fail is because the `nginx` hostname cannot be resolved to an IP address.

It is possible in `docker-compose.yml` to assign static IP addresses to the various containers. Please consider fixed IP addresses and assigning one of them to the `.host` property of your Varnish backend.

This way you avoid the cyclical dependency. Even if the IP address doesn't yet exist, Varnish won't complain. Varnish only connects to the backend when it a cache miss or cache bypass occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is fixed IP Address a really good solution? Will docker work on other systems as the network will be different from mine at home?

Comment: Hostnames are better of course, but you already know what happens with DNS resolution or hostnames that don't exist (yet). An alternative would be to load Varnish with `backend default none` initially and once everything is up and running you can load the actual VCL file via `varnishadm vcl.load` and `varnishadm vcl.use`